# is it possible to publish a message to multiple exchanges from a single app

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, rabbitmq-exchange

I have a stream, wherein there is a source->processor1->processor2->Sink1

I need to push the output of processor1 to another Sink instance (i.e. Sink2).

I need something like

```
                      ______Processor2-----Sink1
                     |
Source-->Processor1--
                     |______Sink2
```

can we bind processor1 output to processor2 and Sink2

I tried binding to multiple exchanges by giving multiple names separated by ;
but did not work.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        bindings:
          processor1-in-0: srcchannel
          processor1-out-0: proc2channel; sink2channel 
      default-binder: rabbit
```

Answer (score 0):

With data flow, you can define 3 streams; the first ending with processor1 with a named output destination.

Then define two more streams to consume from that named destination.

See https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/feature-guides/streams/named-destinations/

Comment: Thank you...  I will try that. I have another issue in processor2. processor2 should send either to Sink1 or to Sink3 based on a condition. Will you please throw some light on this as well

Comment: I could achieve parallel streams with named output destination. Thank you Gary Russel